# Deleting ONLY trailing spaces and spaces in empty fields

Tags: vbscript

I have a CSV with data like below

> "01","567  ","      ","This is a message"

I need to delete the trailing spaces and spaces in blank fields, while leaving the spaces in between data.

My code:

```
Dim inStream : Set inStream...

With inStream

  .open

  .type = 2

  .charset = "utf-8"

  .loadfromfile src

  Dim outStream : Set outStream...

  outStream.open

  outStream.type = 2

  While Not .EOS

    arrLine = split(.read, ",")

    strLine = trim(arrLine(0))

    If ubound(arrLine) > 0 Then
      For intField = 1 To ubound(arrLine)
        strLine = strLine & "," & trim(arrLine(intField))
      Next
    End If

    outStream.write(strLine)
    outStream.savetofile dest, create
  WEnd

  outStream.close

  .close

End With
```

Comment: Cab you give an example of input data and expected result? I don't really get the problem statement "I need to delete the trailing spaces and spaces in blank fields, while leaving the spaces in between data"

Answer (score 0):

You can split your CSV line into an array and then loop through and use the 'Trim' function on each item. 
There are surprisingly good vbscript examples like this on google.

Comment: Tried using with FSO but can't seem to implement with ADODB.Stream.